# Create Azure Load Balancer in existing v-net fears to "Not all Backend IP Configurations referenced by the Load Balancer"

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-virtual-network, azure-vm-scale-set, azure-load-balancer

I try to create a load balancer on azure via powershell, but in case I use an existing vnet from an different resource group I get an error.
(Not all Backend IP Configurations referenced by the Load Balancer). The load balancer should later be used for a VM Scale Set.

But I did not set the v-net and IPs for the BackendAddressPoolConfig, also I do not see how to do this.

```
$vnet= Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name $vnetname -ResourceGroupName $vnetrg -ErrorAction Stop
$subnetMain = $vnet.Subnets[2]
$subNetName = $subnetMain.Name
$frontendIP = New-AzureRmLoadBalancerFrontendIpConfig -Name LB-Frontend `
                                               -SubnetId $subnetMain.Id
$beaddresspool= New-AzureRmLoadBalancerBackendAddressPoolConfig -Name "LB-backend" 
$inboundNATRule1= New-AzureRmLoadBalancerInboundNatRuleConfig -Name "RDP" `
                                           -FrontendIpConfiguration $frontendIP `
                                           -Protocol TCP `
                                           -FrontendPort 3389 `
                                           -BackendPort 3389
$healthProbe = New-AzureRmLoadBalancerProbeConfig -Name "HealthProbe" `
                                           -RequestPath "Default.htm" `
                                           -Protocol http -Port 80 `
                                           -IntervalInSeconds 15 `
                                           -ProbeCount 2
$lbrule = New-AzureRmLoadBalancerRuleConfig -Name "HTTP" `
                                           -FrontendIpConfiguration $frontendIP `
                                           -BackendAddressPool $beAddressPool `
                                           -Probe $healthProbe `
                                           -Protocol Tcp `
                                           -FrontendPort 80 `
                                           -BackendPort 80

$nrplb = New-AzureRmLoadBalancer -ResourceGroupName $currentrg `
                                           -Name "NRP-LB" `
                                           -Location $loc `
                                           -FrontendIpConfiguration $frontendIP `
                                           -InboundNatRule $inboundNATRule1 `
                                           -LoadBalancingRule $lbrule `
                                           -BackendAddressPool $beAddressPool `
                                           -Probe $healthProbe
```

Must I set the IP configuration for the backend? But how? Or is something earls wrong?

Comment: Did you create Internal Loadbalancer ?

Comment: Yes should be internal between an Appgateway and the VM Scale Set. Code to create the Loadbalancer is included in my sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today new Version 6.2.1 of Azure Powershell came out that. This solves the Problem.

See
https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/Releases